# Swiper-slide height stretching image in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html, swiper.js

I have a div with a background image that looks perfectly fine on desktop. But when I switch to mobile, the image becomes stretched top to bottom creating a lot of space between content and the carousel itself which are both inside the div.

Here is the swiper-slide code:

```
   .swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 550px;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Note I set the height to a fixed 550px, which I know is the problem. My question is how to make the height something else while in mobile so that it could look the same as it does in desktop.

Here is the javascript for this specific carousel that I am using:

```
 var swiper1 = new Swiper('#swiper2', {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    slidesPerColumn: 1,
    spaceBetween: 30

});
```

And here are screenshots to show you what is happening on my site.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hV85.jpg

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Add the HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using this

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .swiper-slide {
        height: 350px;
    }
}
```